# Publishing self-contained app .NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Recently, I have installed VS 2017 RC with .NET Core Preview 4 SDK.
In new SDK, there is no `project.json`, only `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>winexe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
     <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup
```

The problem is that now, `dotnet publish` outputs `dll`, not `exe` file.
I have tried to run `dotnet publish -r win10-x64` but it doesn't even compile.

How can I make self-contained application in dotnet 1.1 Preview?
Maybe should I specify `runtime` section in csproj (like it was required in json)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, you're supposed to do the following:

```
dotnet build -r win10-x64
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
```

You need to build it initially.

The other thing to denote, the .csproj and project.json function almost identical.  So the .csproj should be configured:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <DebugType>Portable</DebugType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>9.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161102-2</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

The above is the proper way to specify the core / self contained functionality you're after. You can find a lot of information on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/deploying/).

Comment: Build fails (with win10-x64 flag specified, without - it is ok) - none on nuget packages are recognized.

Comment: Managed to compile, but no luck:
`Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.458.808
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  SquadPlanning -> C:\Users\patry\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SquadPlanning\src\SquadPlanning\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\SquadPlanning.dll` Still dll.

Comment: Commands used: `dotnet build -r win10-x64` and ` dotnet publish -r win10-x64`.

Comment: @pwas You take a look at the site I linked?

Comment: yep. But Docs tells about .net core preview 3, the problem occurs on preview 4. Here is issue I have created on github: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5105